# Spring Data JPA createCountQueryFor replacement?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have an abstract repository class, in which I compute a hibernate query (as String) and for this String I also have to create a count query. Until recently I have used `QueryUtils.createCountQueryFor(String)`, which was marked as deprecated in newer versions of `spring-data-jpa`.

Their solution is to use `DeclaredQuery.deriveCountQuery(String, String)`. However `DeclaredQuery` together with all its implementing subclasses have no public identifier, thus cannot be used outside their packages.

What solutions do I have (using `spring-data-jpa`) to create a count query from a select query, without using this deprecated method?

Answer (score 0):

The best answer for these cases I think is to go directly to the code.

The only implementations for `DeclaredQuery` are [`StringQuery`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/2.1.x/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/query/StringQuery.java) and [`EmptyDeclaredQuery`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/2.1.x/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/query/EmptyDeclaredQuery.java). If we inspect `StringQuery` (for latest branch, currently 2.1.x), is the only internal member that computes a count query like the one you are in need of:

```
@Override
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public DeclaredQuery deriveCountQuery(@Nullable String countQuery, @Nullable String countQueryProjection) {

  return DeclaredQuery
    .of(countQuery != null ? countQuery : QueryUtils.createCountQueryFor(
    query, countQueryProjection));
}
```

But as you can see, this class is still using the deprecated `QueryUtils.createCountQueryFor()` method (note the `@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")` in the method signature) which tells us that even collaborators of `spring-data-jpa` do not have yet an alternative. Thus, I would continue using the deprecated method in the meantime, and keep an eye on that implementation for an alternative on upcoming releases.

As a side note, the fact that `DeclaredQuery` is not a public member tell us that is not part of the public API and it shouldn't be used. I understand your need for a count query though, I found myself in a similar situation some time ago - in that case, we ended up implementing our own version of count query.